# How are Cloud Run URLs generated?

Tags: google-cloud-run

I would like to know if cloud run URLs are generated in a *deterministic way*. I want to know if it's possible to know the URL *before* deployment.

Cloud Run domain mapping is not supported in many of the regions I use. I can use the API *after* deployment to get the URL which it seems like I will wind up having to do, but it would still be nice to know how the URLs are generated.

I deployed the same app/container to multiple regions. Here is an example of 2 URLs:

```
"https://myapp-123yla7opz-uw.a.run.app"
"https://myapp-123yla7opz-ue.a.run.app"
```

How is `123yla7opz` being generated? Is that a known algorithm google uses? Is it generated from the cloud run app name or container name/hash or something?

Comment: It's a uniq hash which is linked to the project but unfortunately there is no way to predict it before hands. Your best bet is using the API to get the generated URL

Comment: Thanks for the info! At least I know for sure now it is not possible.

Comment: @boredabdel - Post your comment as the answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Posting the answer if someone needs it later

It's a uniq hash which is linked to the project but unfortunately there is no way to predict it before hands. Your best bet is using the API to get the generated URL.